# How to populate the current data in the edit form with (Axios, php and vue.js)

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

I'm new in (Axios, PHP, and vue.js), I want to populate the current data in the edit form the form without using the for loop

when I use the code below it does submit the data to the SQL database that I type in the inputs filed

```js
   updateRecord: function (id) {
       let formData = new FormData();
       console.log(formData);
       formData.append('name', this.name);
        formData.append('msisdn', this.msisdn);

       const blackList = {};
         formData.forEach(function(value, key){
          blackList[key] = value;
         });
      axios({
         url: 'http://whizzdev/blackListEdit.php?id=' + id + "&action=update",
          method: 'post',
          data: formData,
          config: {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}
        });
```

```html
  <div class="modal-container">
         <form>
            <label>Name</label>
              <select v-model="name" type="select">
                <option>Prevent MSISDNS from PLAYING</option>
                <option>Prevent MSISDNS from WINNING</option>
              </select>
              <label>Msisdn</label>
              <input type="text" v-model="msisdn">
           </form>
            <button type="submit" value="update" @click="updateRecord(blackList.id)">Save</button>
            <button type="reset" @click="showModal = false">back</button>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should also work without the following code as `blacklist` is not used inside `updateRecord()`:

```
   const blackList = {};
     formData.forEach(function(value, key){
      blackList[key] = value;
     });
```